# Getting YouTube JSON to Python Dict (in Django)

Tags: python, json, django

I'm missing something:
The URL I'm calling is returning JSON, but I can't see it all in my method. Here is an example of what the url returns in the browser:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "type": "multiplePlaylists"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "playlists": [
     "foo",
     "bar",
     "baz"
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I'm doing this:

```
req = urllib2.Request(url)
    try:
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        data = json.load(resp)
        ....
```

But when that runs, `data` looks like this:

```
{u'items': [{u'snippet': {u'type': u'multiplePlaylists'}}]}
```

It's only getting `snippet` and not `contentDetails`.

What I really need is `contentDetails['playlists']`. 
I must be doing something wrong and not getting enough of the JSON.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `url`?

Comment: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channelSections/?key=<api_key>&part=snippet,contentDetails&channelId=UCQxtLzG3ckdfsnxd8MDfx2g&fields=items(contentDetails(playlists),snippet(type))` I can't give you my API key (sorry, it's not mine to give).

Comment: Are the browser URL and the requested URL in the code exactly the same?

Comment: Thank You Simeon!! I was introducing some Garbage in `YOU_TUBE_API_KEY`